# PDO insert error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the code below to work.....

The error:

```
ERRORSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

The code:

```
$data=array($idApplications,$author,$addedOn,$note);
try {
    $STH = $this->DBH->query('
      INSERT INTO '.$table.' (idApplications,Author,NoteAddedOn,Note) 
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
   ');
    $STH->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
}
```

(Using PHP PDO and MySQL)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to create the query string in a variable and then passing it to the query() method

Comment: So instead it would be $query='INSERT INTO....'; $STH->execute($query);? Is there any advantage/disadvantage to this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to prepare a statement, yet you're executing it (via `query()`) instead of preparing it.

Change `->query(...);` to `->prepare(...);` and leave the rest as is...

[PDO::Prepare()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Ah! That solved it. Thanks! :) (As you can tell, I'm still learning PDO!)

Comment: No problem.  We all make mistakes.  The only thing we can do is try to learn from them...